# Why is the permutation from inverses of $1/p$ mod elements of $\{2,\dotsc,p-1\}$ always product of 3-cycles?

Tags: permutations

Let $p$ be an odd prime and for $2 \le q<p$, let
$\genfrac(){}{}1 p_q$ be the unique integer $t \bmod q$ such that $pt=1 \bmod q$. If we write $pt=1+\alpha_qq$, then the map

$$\lambda_p:q-1 \rightarrow \alpha_q$$

is a permutation of $[1,\dotsc,p-2]$. How to prove that as a permutation $\lambda_p$ is always a product of 3-cycles except for $(p-2) \bmod 3$ fixed points ?

$(1,(p-1)/2,p-2)$ is always a 3-cycle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have $pt=1+\alpha_q q$, so $1+\alpha_q q \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and thus $\alpha_q = -1/q \bmod p$. So the permutation $\lambda$ maps $x$ to $-1/(x+1)$, as an operation on $\mathbb{F}_q \cup \{ \infty \}$. We note that $\{ \infty, 0, -1 \}$ forms one cycle for $\lambda$, which explains why $\lambda$ permutes the complementary set $\{ 1,2,\dotsc, p-2 \}$.

We have $\lambda(\lambda(\lambda(x))) = x$. This can be proved by just expanding the algebra, but there is a better way. Given an invertible matrix $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, we define the corresponding Möbius transformation to be $z \mapsto \tfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Composition of Möbius transformations corresponds to multiplication of matrices. The transformation $\lambda$ correspond to the matrix $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0&-1 \\ 1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, and we have $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0&-1 \\ 1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]^3 = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} -1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, corresponding to $z \mapsto \tfrac{-z}{-1} = z$.

Thus, $\lambda$ has order $3$, so it is a union of cycles and fixed points. Finally, we need to figure out how many fixed points there are. We have $z = \tfrac{-1}{z+1}$ iff $z^2+z=-1$ or $z^2+z+1=0$. In other words, $z$ is a primitive cube root of unity. There are two such roots if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, and none if $p \equiv -1 \bmod 3$. (Remark: $z$ is a fixed point of $\tfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ if and only if $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} z\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is an eigenvector of $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{smallmatrix} \right]$, which might be another good way to think about this.)

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you. There is a misprint on the first line $\alpha_qq=-1 \mod p$.